# Can streams in flutter be left open?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, mobile-application

**TL;DR : Can I leave streams open in flutter?**

I have a certain UI to be made that requires a different style of app drawer, not like a normal one where the side drawer comes sliding from the left to the top of the main screen.
The design is more like the whole main screen moves to the right and there is a layer at the bottom of it that acts as the sidebar.

To make it clear, think of it like instead of the drawer being on top of the screen and moving, the reverse is what I want. I want the main screen to be on the top and drawer at the bottom (in terms of z-index) and the main screen moving.

What I have done is I have created two widgets, one for app drawer and another for the main screen, and using stack widget and some animations, made it work. For registering the user's feedback about which screen he/she wants to open, I am passing data from that sidebar widget to the main screen widget using streams and storing that in the local state of the main screen and showing whatever needs to be shown based on that.

I am attaching code below:

This is the main file where I use stack and animations to make the UI work:

[image: main file]

This is how I am registering user's feedback and sending it to the mainscreen, using streams:

[image]

And this is how I am receiving the feedback and showing what page has to be shown:

[image]

This is how my stream/bloc class looks like:

[image]

My main question here is about the approach, is there any better way of doing it? I am asking that because I know streams are not supposed to be left open and that affects the app performance. **But with this approach, I have to leave it open all the time as the user should be able to select the desired page at any given time.**

Is it a normal practice to leave streams open in such scenarios, can you tell me some cases where streams have to be left open if such cases exist? (Eg. I think autosuggest/search-as-you-type might be using streams all the time, is it so?).

Comment: Yes, you can leave streams open, if that's what required. It shouldn't affect performance. On the other hand, if the stream is no longer required, then you should close it. In your case, that is when the Widget that creates the `SidebarHandlingBloc` is being disposed.

Comment: But It is never being disposed. If I test it using a print statement inside the dispose function, it is never printed to the console.

Comment: Make sense, you need that drawer in your entire app. When your app is closed/recycled by the OS, it'll be clean up

Comment: That's correct, I understand that. But my question was only about when the app is running, if it will impact the performance. And if there is any better approach to attain this UI.

Comment: No, it will not affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can leave a stream open.
But it will impact your app performance and in my opinion it's a complex approach for a simple callback action.
Here's what I would do:

** in the Drawer's page:
// add a callback parameter

```
final Function(Widget w) onItemTap;
```

// add the callback to the drawer's constructor

```
Drawer(this.onItemTap);
```

** in The Drawer's gesture detector:
// on tapping on an item, send this callback to the page where you have instantiated the drawer page.

```
onTap(){ widget.onItemTap( WidgetToShow() ) },
```

Now when you instantiate the drawer class anywhere in your mainscreen you have a callback parameter you can use like this:

```
Drawer( onItemTap:(Widget w){ 
// now you have your widget in the mainScreen, do as you want with it 
}  )
```

So here's your final drawer/menu's code:

```
class Drawer extends StatefulWidget {
final Function(Widget w) onItemTap;
Drawer(this.onItemTap);
}
// ....
GestureDetector(
onTap: (){ return widget.onItemTap( WidgetToShow() ); },
),
// ...
```

and here's your main screen code:

```
// ...
stack(
children:[
Drawer( onItemTap:(Widget w){ 
// now you have your widget in the mainScreen, do as you want with it 
}  ),
]
),
//...
```